# Swift Nested Structure Access

Tags: swift

I have the following nested structure:

```
public struct Session {
    public enum Type: Int {
        FirstLaunch = 0, NotRegistered, LoggedOut, LoggedIn
    }
}
```

It's very simple, very barebones. However when I try to access `FirstLaunch` for example, Xcode throws the following error:

```
'Session.Type.Type' does not have a member named 'FirstLaunch'
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: This is a bad error message and probably worth an official bug report.

Answer (score 5):

`Type` is a reserved word in Swift. You can escape it by surrounding it with back ticks.

> “If you need to give a constant or variable the same name as a
>   reserved Swift keyword, you can do so by surrounding the keyword with
>   back ticks (`) when using it as a name. However, you should avoid
>   using keywords as names unless you have absolutely no choice.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

Comment: THIS. Another reason why to not give generic names to your times.

Comment: Take away here is "you should avoid using keywords as names unless you have absolutely no choice."

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Looks like you can't use the word `Type` to name any structure. It's probably a reserved keyword or something of that nature.